# Contador no model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Estou buscando uma forma de adicionar uma variavel com incremento para adicionar ao id de uma div, alguem poderia me dizer a forma mais recomendada de fazer isso?

minha dificildade em fazer esse incremento se deve ao **cocoon** que é usado pra chamar esse render

```
<%= link_to_add_association '+', f, :filtro_questoes,
        'data-association-insertion-node' => "#filter_q",
        'data-association-insertion-method' => "append", id: 'add', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

já tentai acessar o atributo do objeto
**<%= f.count %>**, **@count**, mas nada deu certo

obs: Se tiver uma forma melhor de fazer isso sem chamar o atributo do model também ta valendo =D

preciso melhorar meu conhecimento em ruby, mas tenho que terminar logo o que estou fazendo.

model

```
class Carro < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :count

    belongs_to :person

    def self.count(n = 0)
        @count = n+1
    end

    def self.count
        @count
    end

end
```

view

```
<div class="control-group nested-fields">

    <div id="carro_div_n <%= f.count %>" class="row form-group" style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">
      <div class="field">
        <h3>Descrição...</h3>
        <%= f.label :carro_id %>
      </div>

      <div class="field col-xs-3">
        <%= f.label :marca_id %>
        <%= f.select :marca_id, 
        options_for_select(
          @marcas.collect { |marca|
          [marca.name.titleize, marca.id] }, 0), {prompt: 'Selecionar marca'}, { id: 'marcas_select', class: 'form-control'} %>
      </div>
      <div id="div_modelo_n" class="field col-xs-3">
        <%= f.label :modelo_id %>
      <%= f.select :modelo_id, options_for_select(@modelos.collect { |modelo|
          [modelo.name.titleize, modelo.id] }, 0), {}, { id: 'modelos_select', class: 'form-control' } %>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox form-group col-xs-2">
        <%= link_to_remove_association "remove tarefa", f, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pra que vc quer usar esse count?

Answer (score 1):

Primeira coisa, quando você insere o `self` à um método ele vira um método estático, `static` no `Java`, ou seja, você deve chamá-lo assim: `Carro.count`.

Se você deseja um id, simplesmente use o `id` do carro: `Carro.id`

Mas se realmente deseja fazer uma contagem, faça isso na hora de mostrar todos os carros. Por exemplo se você estiver usando um `each` para mostrar todos os carros:

```
<% Carro.all.each_with_index do |carro, count| %>
    <div id="<%= carro.count %>">
        ...
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou ao invés de `<%= f.count %>` usar `<%= @carro.count %>` ?

Comment: eu Já tinha resolvido isso em js, mas a pagina precisa atualizar para o script funcionar, então adicionei o código dentro do <body> da pagina,  funcionou sem a necessidade do F5, você sabe me dizer por que isso ocorre? estou achando que isso acontece por causa do rails e não do próprio js